# How can i custom design nb-stepper header, or make its direction RTL?

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

i'm using nb-stepper component from nebular UI in ngx-admin
i want to reverse the stepper direction to RTL instead of LTR

using dev tools in chrome i could access the stepper header and change the direction using `{ flex-flow: row-reverse; }` but i can't seem to be able to add any css styling to it through my angular app

i can't seem to find any helpful answer anywhere

here's what i'm trying to do
[image]

Answer (score 0):

RTL

All Nebular components support RTL out of the box.

The components that accept a position as a setting now also support logical start and end values, similar to flexbox. The value of start and end depends on the current layout direction. For LTR it's left and for RTL - right. For instance, if we need the sidebar to be positioned logically depending on a language direction, then instead of setting it to left we can set its position to start:

```
<nb-sidebar start></nb-sidebar>
```

Document direction could be set through the NbThemeModule.forRoot call. Supported values are ltr and rtl.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NbThemeModule.forRoot(nbThemeOptions, nbJSThemes, nbMediaBreakpoints, 'rtl')
  ]
})
```

Default value is ltr.

> NOTE: Components must be placed inside of the  component to correctly support language direction.
> To help you add RTL support to your custom components, Nebular provides you with two scss mixins: nb-lrt and nb-rtl. You can use them to alter values of css properties, which don't support logical values, like paddings, margins, etc. You can pass single property and value as arguments, pass multiple statements as the content of mixin or both. For example:

```
:host {
    @include nb-ltr(padding-left, 1em);
    @include nb-rtl(padding-right, 1em);
}

:host {
    @include nb-ltr() {
        padding-left: 1em;
    };

    @include nb-rtl() {
        padding-right: 1em;
    };
}
```

Please note, the mixins are only available within **component :host** selector or nb-install-component() mixin if used.

If you need to change direction dynamically, get current value or listen to changes of direction, Nebular provides NbLayoutDirectionService.

for more information please [visit](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/usability/righttoleft-rtl#nblayoutdirectionservice)

Comment: thanks for answering extensively, this could help me solve a different problem i have. at the end i only added `dir = 'rtl'` attribute to the nb-stepper tag and it worked

Comment: glad to hear that :-)